# Need to update specific key value, put or post?

Tags: java, rest

I'm coding an automated test in Java which firsts creates a set of preconditions in my application using the existing API and then, during the executions of the tests, I need to update a specific value of a key in order to execute a different scenario. As this is a REST service, I need to use PUT or POST method. Which one is the one to pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an existing API: use the one it tells you to.

If it doesn't tell you which one, then use the one that works.

If both work, then read a decade worth of "PUT v POST" debates and decide on your own.

(I personally vote for PUT.)